# jquery .ajax cache issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "something.cfm",
  data: formData,
  cache: false,
  success: function (result) {
    $("#formSub").html(
      '<input type="button" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" class="submitButton save" value="Save" disabled="disabled"/>'
    );
  },
  error: function (xmlHttpRequest, status, err) {
    confirm("Error!" + err);
  },
});
```

On IE8 or IE7, sometimes the success function does not run and the disabled btnSave does not appear. So, people keep submitting the same form over and  While working on another application, I found out that the `cache:false` does not seem to work.

Comment: `cache` Default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp'
If set to false it will force the pages that you request to not be cached by the browser. ::: how do you know that the result is being cached? Could it POSSIBLY be anything else?

Comment: Have you try looking for the 'complete' event handler?

Comment: Looking at jQuery's source, the cache parameter is only honored if you're doing a GET request, not a post.  It doesn't really make sense at all for a POST request to get cached.  That sounds like something that even Microsoft wouldn't mess up.

Comment: You can also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16418592/1027017) answer

Comment: You can always try a "dirty" solution and add a random string to end of the URL. You can also try chaining an **always** function to the end of your ajax call https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/